# The class 'App\Repository\Users\UserRepository' was not found in the chain configured namespaces App\Entity\Users

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, repository

I've seen a few questions about this error message but the answers weren't helpful to me so here we go again:

I have 2 configured entity managers and when I call

`dump($this->getManager('db_users')->getRepository(UserRepository::class));`

it throws the error

> The class 'App\Repository\Users\UserRepository' was not found in the
> chain configured namespaces App\Entity\Users.

So it's the repository problem (or isn't it? Symfony likes to throw errors absolutely not related to the real problem).

**List of my files:**

**UserRepository.php** (nothing special... just added `\Users` to the namespace to be the same as real directory path)

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Repository\Users;

use App\Entity\Users\User;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordUpgraderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

class UserRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository implements PasswordUpgraderInterface
{
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, User::class);
    }

    /**
     * Used to upgrade (rehash) the user's password automatically over time.
     */
    public function upgradePassword(UserInterface $user, string $newEncodedPassword): void
    {
        if (!$user instanceof Uzytkownik) {
            throw new \Exception(sprintf('Instances of "%s" are not supported.', \get_class($user)));
        }

        $user->setPassword($newEncodedPassword);
        $this->_em->persist($user);
        $this->_em->flush();
    }
}
```

**User.php** (everything here is valid, I'm sure. User.php is inside `src/Entity/Users/`)

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Entity\Users;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\{UserInterface, EquatableInterface};
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/** 
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\Users\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="t_users")
 */
class User implements UserInterface, EquatableInterface, \Serializable
{
...
}
```

**Services.yaml** (standard... I see all my repos under `bin/console debug:container` command so it seems like I don't need to configure repositories here)

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true

    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'

    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

**doctrine.yaml** (also perfectly configured as the documentation suggests: https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html)

```
orm:
    default_entity_manager: db_users
    
    entity_managers:
        db_users:
            connection: db_users
            mappings:
                User:
                    is_bundle: false
                    type: annotation
                    dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Users'
                    prefix: 'App\Entity\Users'
                    alias: User

        db_core:
            connection: db_core
            mappings:
                Core:
                    is_bundle: false
                    type: annotation
                    dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Core'
                    prefix: 'App\Entity\Core'
                    alias: Core
```

I tried to add `\\` to

`@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\Users\UserRepository")` so result would be

`@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="\App\Repository\Users\UserRepository")`

but it is not suggested probably and it also comes with such error:

> The "\App\Repository\Users\UserRepository" entity repository
> implements
> "Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepositoryInterface",
> but its service could not be found. Make sure the service exists and
> is tagged with "doctrine.repository_service.

Well then I tagged it like this:

```
App\Repository\Users\:
    resource: '../src/Repository/Users'
    tags: ['doctrine.repository_service']

App\Repository\Core\:
    resource: '../src/Repository/Core'
    tags: ['doctrine.repository_service']
```

and the same error occurred even when I deleted **var** folder :)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I ran a quick test and things work as expected with a single entity manager.  You don't need to explicitly tag the repositories so you can get rid of those lines in services.yaml.  See if "bin/console doctrine:mapping:info --em=db_users" returns the expected results.

Comment: Never mind.  The answer below will solve the problem though you still want to take the tagging stuff out of services.yaml.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to pass the **entity class name**, instead of the repository class name, like this:

```
->getRepository(User::class)
```

Comment: Wish I could upvote you 100 times. Thanks!